# Как записать в объект массив строк С++

Tags: c++

Конструктор класса User:

```
    User(string fio[2], double telefoneNumber, int accountBalance) 
        {
            this->fio[0] = fio[0];
            this->fio[1] = fio[1];
            this->fio[2] = fio[2];
    
            this->telefoneNumber = telefoneNumber;
            
            this->accountBalance = accountBalance;
        }
```

Вызов это конструктора:

```
int main()
{
    User firstuser({ "Cucumber", "Andrey", "Ananasovich" }, 88005553535, 500);
}
```

Строка { "Cucumber", "Andrey", "Ananasovich" } вызывает ошибку. Как правильно будет записать свойства в объект firstuser
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Использовать [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), тогда сломанная строка будет `User firstUser(std::array<std::string, 3>{"Cucumber", "Andrey", "Ananasovich"}, 88005553535, 500);`, а конструктор `User(std::array<std::string, 3> const& fio, double telefoneNumber, int accountBalance)`

Comment: А можно ли при этом сохранить массив строк?

Comment: Как минимум, при объявлении `string fio[2]` обращаться к `this->fio[2] = fio[2];` — выход за границы и UB... Да и номер телефона в виде `double`, мягко говоря, смущает.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, данные ошибки исправил, но можно ли как-то исправить ошибку не используя array (совет anton)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, можно, например, вот так

```
struct User
{
    string fio[2];

    User(initializer_list<string> fio)
    {
        auto it = fio.begin();
        this->fio[0] = *it++;
        this->fio[1] = *it;
    }

    void out()
    {
        cout << fio[0] << "  " << fio[1] << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    User u({"aaa","bbb"});
    u.out();
}
```

Но это по сути означает оказаться персонажем того анекдота — "*о, месье понимает толк в извращениях!*"...

Это С++, и решать проблемы надо в его рамках. Не обязательно через `array`, можно и вот так — но тогда лучше использовать вектор строк, что-то вроде

```
    vector<string> fio;

    User(initializer_list<string> fio):fio(fio)
    {
```